# How to handle error responses in a REST endpoint that accepts different Accept header values.

Tags: rest, error-handling, content-type, http-accept-header

I'm trying to add a new content type to a REST endpoint. Currently it only returns json but I now need to be able to return also a CSV file.

As far as I know, the best way to do this is by using the `Accept` header with value `text/csv` and then add a converter that is able to react to this and convert the returned body to the proper `CSV` representation.

I've been able to do this but then I have a problem handling exceptions. Up until know, all the errors returned are in `json`. The frontend expects any `500` status code to contain a specific body with the error. But now, by adding the option to return either `application/json` or `text/csv` to my endpoint, in case of an error, the converter to be used to transform the body is going to be either the `jackson` converter or my custom one depending on the `Accept` header passed. Moreover, my frontend is going to need to read the `content-type` returned and parse the value based on the type of representation returned.

Is this the normal approach to handle this situation?

A faster workaround would be to forget about the `Accept` header and include a url parameter indicating the format expected. Doing it this way, I'd be able to change the `content-type` of the response and the parsing of the data directly in the controller as the `GET` request won't include any `Accept` header and it will be able to accept anything. There are some parts of the code already doing this where the only expected response format is `CSV` so I'm going to have a difficult time defending the use of the `Accept` header unless there is a better way of handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my frontend is going to need to read the content-type returned and parse the value based on the type of representation returned.
>
> Is this the normal approach to handle this situation?

Yes.

For example, [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) describes a common format for describing problems.  So the server would send an `application/problem+json` or an `application/problem+xml` representation of the issue in the response, along with the usual meta data in the headers.

Consumers that understand `application/problem+json` can parse the data with in, and forward a useful description of the problem to the user/logs whatever.  Consumers that *don't* understand that representation are limited to acting on the information in the headers.

> A faster workaround would be to forget about the Accept header and include a url parameter indicating the format expected.

That's also fine -- more precisely, you can have a different resource responsible for the each of the different media-types that you support.

It may be useful to review [section 3.4 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4), which describes the semantics of content negotiation.

Comment: I wasn't expecting an answer saying that using a parameter is also fine but I have actually found discussions related to this, also adding a third option that is using extensions (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139654/rest-tradeoffs-between-content-negotiation-via-accept-header-versus-extensions). For what I understand, in the end is a trade-off between being pragmatic/academic given there are plenty of discussions about the interpretation of the protocol and the REST paper.